# Removing key from kryptonite lock

Tags: lock

I can't remove the key, or open, my brand new Kryptonite lock. I can twiddle the key with about 60 degrees of movement from current position; and have attempted every movement I can think of. Have tried putting a drop of lubricant in to see if it would help.

Any advice?

[image: Kryptonite lock]

UPDATE: was impossible to remove the key, so it got sent back to the retailer for a refund. I would never buy a Kryptonite lock again, if it had been on my bike this would have been a complete disaster.

Comment: Mine has 180 degrees of movement and opens clockwise.  Try compressing the bar into the U - there may be tension on the lock.

Comment: Also (though you may have tried this) at both ends of the travel try pushing the key in quite firmly and jiggling in /out. I've got a different model but on mine at least you can only take the key out with it locked (which is why i wouldn't buy one again). It also has 180 degrees of movement.

Comment: Take it back to the shop. Might be a defect in manufacturing. If it's acting up this soon, it's better to get it replaced now than worry about the lock sticking when it's connecting your bike to a rack.

Comment: For some reason, I've always had this problem with new Kryptonite locks.

Comment: It's a pretty serious design flaw. Just thankful it wasn't attached to my bike at the time.

Comment: Probably the bar is not all the way shoved into the lock, but a decent lock shouldn't do this.  (However, from what I can tell, no one has produced a decent bike lock in about 15 years.)

Comment: I've had a couple of Kryptonite locks and they have all been incredibly sensitive to the position of the key in the lock barrel, both for locking and unlocking. The key had to be put right to the back of the barrel to get it to turn properly 90 degrees. (Not that I'm saying yours isn't faulty necessarily)

Comment: I have three I use regularly, they can be a bit touchy.  I find that most of the time you have to check the lock bar is all the way in or that the key needs a slight turn.  Another thing, if you don't use that frame mount, take it off and wrapp the spot in black electric tape.  It will scratch your frame easily while riding.

Comment: Prepare the worse case : they pair the wrong key.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this helps, but I lost keys to krypto lock (in 2010) and was offered free of charge replacement keys by the manufacturer, sent to me inclusive of postage..../ maybe they could fix at the factory and give you a new key set for minimal cost while extracting the faulty key??

Answer (score 1):

I hate to sound like a caveman but in addition to the lubricant-props to you for doing that on your own- you might want to get a hammer and try to tap it-the key or the lock- just to see if it'll help. I know my Kryptonite cable lock has become rusted from being in the elements and bound up a couple times before I could soak it with WD-40. Jimmying it and tapping were what helped there. Lucky for you your lock isn't on the bike. Hope that helps.

Comment: If you do try this (and I wouldn't recommend it on a new lock) be sure to only tap the key into the lock - any sideways force is too likely to snap it.

Comment: This is a brand new lock. If it needs tapping with a hammer then it needs to be returned because it's defective.

Answer (score 1):

Community poked this.
Take the blunt end and strike it on concrete.
Really I have done this to free keys.
Don't go for the hammer first but some times a hammer is what you end up with.